# Adding a search box to a windows forms web browser control that highlights text

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a windows forms (using c#) application. It displays a webpage and has a textbox/botton combination which can be used to search for text displayed to the user. Currently I search the inner text of all elements for the text in the textbox. And then I weed out the elements that are redundant (for example a word could be in a 'p' and 'b' element where the 'b' is a child element of 'p' so the element returned should be 'b'). Finally I run the ScrollIntoView(true) method on the found element.

I'd now like to add a function that highlights the text (like if you search for a term in a real webbrowser). My first thought was to just inject html and or javascript code around the text but that seems like a messy solution.

Any ideas on how I should do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's an article that shows you how to do this. http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/13/highlight-words-in-webbrowser-control/

Comment: Thanks, but that solution injects html into the page which could mess up the layout and I'm trying to avoid that route. I found a link on that page that tries to do it with javascript though and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this topic is quite old but I encountered the same issue than the topic author and  during all the search I made to solve this, I finally found my answer. So I'm taking the opportunity to share it here.

Here are the methods that I'm using to perform my search in my WebBrowser and to highlight the  word found:

```
private bool FindFirst(string text)
  {
     var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
     var sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;
     sel.empty(); // get an empty selection, so we start from the beginning
     var rng = sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
     if (rng != null && rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
     {
        rng.select();
        rng.scrollIntoView(false);
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="text"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public bool FindNext(string text)
  {
     var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
     var sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;
     var rng = sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
     if (rng != null)
     {
        rng.collapse(false); // collapse the current selection so we start from the end of the previous range
        if (rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
        {
           rng.select();
           rng.scrollIntoView(false);
           return true;
        }
        else
           return FindFirst(text);
     }
     return false;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="text"></param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  public bool FindPrevious(string text)
  {
     var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
     var sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;
     var rng = sel.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
     if (rng != null)
     {

        rng.collapse(true); // it should be true,so it goes to start of the document
        var found = rng.findText(text, -1, 0); // Range count value should give negative value
        if(!found)
        {
           rng.moveEnd("textedit");
           found = rng.findText(text, -1, 0);
        }
        if (found)
        {
           rng.select();
           rng.scrollIntoView(false);
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
```

The only "problem" with this piece of code is that only one occurrence of the found words is selected at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Just take input from the user in a textbox [here txtNoteSearch] and then follow the following code to implement the search. Following code demonstrates the search and highlight.

```
private void WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc2 = WebBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
    string ReplacementTag = "<span style='background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);'>";
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(doc2.body.outerHTML);
    string HTMLString = strBuilder.ToString();
    if (this.m_NoteType == ExtractionNoteType.SearchResult)
    {
        List<string> SearchWords = new List<string>();
        SearchWords.AddRange(this.txtNoteSearch.Text.Trim.Split(" "));
        foreach (string item in SearchWords)
        {
            int index = HTMLString.IndexOf(item, 0, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            // 'If index > 0 Then
            while ((index > 0 && index < HTMLString.Length))
            {
                HTMLString = HTMLString.Insert(index, ReplacementTag);
                HTMLString = HTMLString.Insert(index + item.Length + ReplacementTag.Length, "</span>");
                index = HTMLString.IndexOf(item, index + item.Length + ReplacementTag.Length + 7, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
    }
    doc2.body.innerHTML = HTMLString;
}
```